# How do I create typeclass Eq by using instance for tree?

Tags: haskell, types, tree

I wanted to create a ternary tree with a node label `n` to the instance of `Eq`. Not only two identical trees should be made equal, but also two trees, which become identical by flip operations. So I thought about something like this:

```
data TernaryTree n = Leaf | Node n (TernaryTree n) (Ternarytree n) (TernaryTree n)

instance Eq TernaryTree where
     Node n l m r == Node n l r m == Node n m l r == Node n m r l == Node n r l m == Node n r m l = True
```

The **error message** is: Parse error in pattern: (Node n l m r) == (Node n l r m)

Comment: What you have written is simply not Haskell syntax. You can only bind names - each binding must be unique - or pattern match on constructors in the pattern of a function. In this case it *must* be something of the form `<pat> == <pat> = <expr>`. The rest of the "logic" of your code must be captured in what is written on the right hand side of the `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definition is wrong since it resembles the following

```
f :: Int -> Int
f (f (f x)) = x
-- compare it with x == y == z = True
```

The above code is meaningless: how would one evaluate that? Further, you can not even use a variable more than once in the same pattern: e.g.

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f x x = x    -- wrong
```

What you need to do is:

```
instance Eq n => Eq (TernaryTree n) where
  Node n l m r == Node n' l' m' r' =   -- all the variables MUST have distinct names
       (n==n' && l==l' && r==r' && m==m') ||
       (n==n' && l==l' && r==m' && m==r') ||   -- last 2 flipped
       ...                                     -- add all cases here
  Leaf         == Leaf             = True
  _            == _                = False
```

If the syntax seems confusing you can put the `(==)` in prefix position:

```
instance Eq n => Eq (TernaryTree n) where
  (==) (Node n l m r) (Node n' l' m' r') =
       (n==n' && l==l' && r==r' && m==m') ||
       ...                                     -- add all cases here
  (==) Leaf           Leaf               = True
  (==) _              _                  = False
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed your steps but now he's annoyed by: Expecting one more argument to ‘TernaryTree’
    The first argument of ‘Eq’ should have kind ‘*’,
      but ‘TernaryTree’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Eq (TernaryTree)’

Comment: @SiXa, I believe I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`(==)` is just a function. For now, let's pretend it's a prefix function called `f`. In that case, we define a concrete example `f` as:

```
f :: Maybe a -> a
f (Just x) = x
f Nothing = error "nothing!"
```

Thus we can have multiple definitions for `f`.

In your case, this would look something like this:

```
instance Eq n => Eq (TernaryTree n) where
  (Node n1 l1 m1 r1) == (Node n2 l2 m2 r2) = (n1 == n2) && ( 
    ((l1 == l2) && (m1 == m2) && (r1 == r2)) ||
    ((l1 == m2) && (l2 == m1) && (r1 == r2)) ||
    ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I followed your steps but now he's annoyed by: Expecting one more argument to ‘TernaryTree’ The first argument of ‘Eq’ should have kind ‘’, but ‘TernaryTree’ has kind ‘ -> *’ In the instance declaration for ‘Eq (TernaryTree)’

Comment: Eric, why would you use that guard? It looks rather asymmetrical?

Comment: @dfeuer Better than duplicating it however many times. It'd be the same in each case.

Comment: Oh I see what you're getting at now.

Answer (score 0):

This does the same as all the rest, perhaps a bit more slowly, but with less code.

```haskell
import Data.List (permutations)

data TernaryTree n = Leaf
                   | Node n (TernaryTree n) (Ternarytree n) (TernaryTree n)

instance Eq n => Eq (TernaryTree n) where
  (Node n1 l1 m1 r1) == (Node n2 l2 m2 r2)
    | n1 /= n2 = False
    | otherwise = any (== [l1,m1,r1]) (permutations [l2,m2,r2])
```